# Average(IF) Multiple Columns

Tags: arrays, excel, function, if-statement, average

I have been trying to find an answer to this online and I don't understand it well enough to do it myself. Long story short, I'm trying to average multiple columns of number data based upon if the column matches criteria. I've tried =AVERAGE(IF(D2:N28=P16,E2:N28))
 but it only seems to average the first column in the range of columns that contain numbers to average.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for the `AVERAGEIF` function seen [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/averageif-function-HA010047433.aspx).  Here's an example that averages the cells A1, A2, B1 and B2 only if the number is above 10.

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:B2, ">10")
```

You may want to add some error handling in case none of the cells match the criteria.  If none match, the cell will display `#DIV/0!`.